# Using aria-describedby and a screenreader-only element, not read out by some screenreaders

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I am attempting to give screenreader users some additional information about a list of links and what they represent.

Rather than putting an aria-label on a `<ul>`, which I understand is discouraged, I have put a screenreader only element in place. I have then bound the and this element together using `aria-describedby`.

```
<span id="describer" aria-hidden=true> I'm a screenreader only element hidden with CSS</span>
<ul aria-describedby="describer">...</ul>
```

This seems to be suggested as the correct use for `aria-describedby` and it works excellently when using VoiceOver on OSX. When a user navigates over the `<ul>` the describer text is read out.

However, it does not work on NVDA, nor does it work on VoiceOver iOS, or TalkBack on Android. It does not read out the screenreader only text.

I am struggling to find a solution that satisfies the major screenreaders (VO, NVDA, TalkBack, JAWS).

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I’m confused just like Quentin: In your title you claim to use a _screenreader-only_ element, but in your example code the description is visible for all except screenreaders…

Answer (score 2):

When an element has `aria-hidden=true`, it's totally removed from the accessibility tree, as if it didn't exists at all for screen readers.

In the `aria-describedby` attribute, you are referencing an element supposed to be absent from the accessibility tree. So you have obviously created an undefined behavior. Some screen readers will consider aria-hidden=true stronger than `aria-describedby` and so will behave as if it didn't exists, while some other screen readers will consider `aria-describedby` stronger and read the description although it's supposed to be hidden.

It's not very clear why you would do something as in your example. Why do you hide the element from the accessibility tree if it should be a description for something else?
Why do you hide it in the first place then?

Additionally, `aria-describedby`, just like `aria-label` and `aria-labelledby`, may not work with all screen readers when applied to a non-interactive element.
The safest alternative to present different content for normal and screen reader users on non-interactive elements is by using visually hidden text, like this:

```html
<span class="sr_only">This text is read by screen readers, but invisible on screen</span>
<span aria-hidden="true">This text is visible on screen, but ignored by screen readers</span>
```

You will find the corresponding `sr_only` CSS class in popular frameworks, sometimes called `visually-hidden` or `screenreader` or `screen-reader`.

Comment: If I don't apply `aria-hidden=true` to the element, then on VO on OSX it is read out twice. Once when the screenreader (rather unattractively) targets the element and again when it gets to the element it is `describedby` linked to.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. It doesn't looks like an especially abnormal behavior. However, it seems that VO on MacOS has difficulties with a lot of small things which works perfectly well elsewhere including VO on iOS. VO on MacOS should probably not be taken as the base reference for testing.